# Fetch Azure VM Size List along with VM Type

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-vm

Need help in fetching the list of Azure VM's along with there type/category(e.g. General, Compute Intensive etc.) refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes

I understand that the Azure API provides the list VM's)Size, configuration etc.) supported in a subscription for a given region  refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/workspacesandcomputes/virtualmachinesizes/list

However we want to list VM's somewhat similar to below

[image]

Comment: Jim, Tried using the code, it does return back the VM Name and configuration, how do we decipher if the machine is General purpose, Memory optimized, compute optimized etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list azure vm resource sku with C#, please refer to the following steps:

1. Create a service principal and assign Contributor role to the sp

```
az login
#create sp and assign Contributor role at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "your service principal name"
```

[image]

2. Code. I use the package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent`

```
 string clientId = "<sp appID>";
            string clientSecret = "<sp passowrd>";
            string tenantId = "";
            string subscriptionId = "";
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    tenantId,
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                        .Configure()
                        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                        .Authenticate(credentials)                       
                        .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            IPagedCollection<IComputeSku> skus = await azure.ComputeSkus.ListbyRegionAndResourceTypeAsync(Region.AsiaSouthEast, ComputeResourceType.VirtualMachines);

            // process data according to your need
                   //get B-series VMs size
                   var newSkus =skus.Where(sku => sku.Inner.Family == "standardBSFamily").ToList();
```

For more details, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-dotnet-list-compute-skus) and [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list)